# What priority are CSS styles applied? Example provided that is confusing me

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I know this should be a stupidly easy topic, but I'm confused and I spent way longer than I should trying to understand this example that my professor gave us.

From what I understand, the rules are *supposed* to be that you go first for inline css, then document css, then external css, and then priority. The priority was from what I thought 100*IDs+10*Class+1*Element reference.

Here is the code that's really confusing me below:

```html
<div id="id1">
  <ul>
    <li class="c1" id="id2">Item 1</li> 
    <li class="c2 c3">Item 2</li>
    <li class="c3">Sublist:   
      <ul>
        <li class="c1">Subitem 1</li>
        <li class="c2">Subitem 2</li>
        <li class="c2" id=”id3”>Subitem 3</li>
      </ul></li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="id4">
    <ul>
      <li id="id5">One thing</li>
      <li id="id6" class="c2">And another thing</li>
      <li id="id7" class="c1">A third thing.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
div > li 
{
  color: yellow;
}
.c2
{
  color: red;
}
ul li+li+li
{
  color: green;
}
#id1, #id4 
{
     color: orange;
}
#id7 
{
  color: blue;
}
</style>
```

In the above code though, item 2 is red, sublist(+subitem1) are green, etc. How is that possible? Why isn't everything coming out orange? Shouldn't the #id1 style be applied to everything automatically since it is the only one with an ID specifier(and everything is a child of div with id="id1"?

Comment: 'ID1' is the id of Parent Div. And you have added the CSS for Child elements. Normally Child Element Style overrides the Parent Element Style.

Comment: ["As per CSS rules, directly targeted element will always take precedence over rules which an element inherits from its ancestor."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The priority formula you wrote is ok if you have two rules to same element.

In css child element inherits from parents the colors, like in your example.

If new rules, despite having a lower specificity number, is applied to child, this override the inheritance.

Anyway read this: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

An element's style overrides it's inheritance.In cases when a style was not defined we will prefer inherited value over default.

Answer (score 0):

There is misunderstanding.

- It did orange at first place to all tags .but later as some of the tags are defined different according to css, then it changes to specified color that you mentioned in css.

For CSS types:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/qt/aatypesofcss.htm

**edited**.